# Mail not firing in particular system

Tags: c#, .net, networking

From my windows application I am sending mail, its working fine in my home network but in another network after installing the application tool is working fine but mail is not firing.I think in that network SMTP `ports(25,465,587)` is blocked.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   

    try
    {
        MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        m.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
        m.To.Add(new MailAddress("xyz@gmail.com"));
        string SUBJECT = string.Empty;       
            SUBJECT = "TestMail";      

        sb.Append("Hi Its a test mail <b/><br/><br/>");

        m.Subject = SUBJECT;
        m.Body = sb.ToString();
        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Timeout = 25000;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "********");
        smtp.Send(m);
        MessageBox.Show("Email has been send");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should Allowing **less secure apps to access your account**

Google may block sign-in attempts from some apps or devices that do not use modern security standards. Since these apps and devices are easier to break into, blocking them helps keep your account safe.

Some examples of apps that do not support the latest security standards include:

- The Mail app on your iPhone or iPad with version 6 or below
- The Mail app on your Windows phone preceding the 8.1 release
- Some Desktop mail clients like Microsoft Outlook and Mozilla
  Thunderbird

**Change account access for less secure apps**

- Go to the ["Less secure apps"](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1) section in My Account.
- Next to "Access for less secure apps," select Turn on. (Note to GSuite users: This setting is hidden if your administrator has locked less secure app account access.)

If you still can't sign in to your account, the ["password incorrect"](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6009563) error might be caused by a different reason.